# Moebius transformation on circles

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

I'm working on a program that draws the limit sets of Schottky groups defined by pairs of circles. If circle $C$ with radius $r$ is centered at $P$, then to map that circle to some other circle $C'$ with radius $s$ centered at $Q$, one can use the transformation $T(z) = \displaystyle{\frac{s(z-P)+rQ}{r}}$ with matrix representation $T = \begin{bmatrix} s & -sP + rQ \\ 0 & r \end{bmatrix}$.

I'm currently using the algorithm to perform Moebius transforms on circles as detailed on pg. 91 of the book Indra's Pearls, which gives equations for these parameters as

$\begin{align*}
z &= P - \frac{r^2}{\overline{\displaystyle{\frac{d}{c}}+P}} \\
Q &= \frac{az+b}{cz+d}\\
s &= \left | \frac{a(P+r)+b}{c(P+r)+d} \right |
\end{align*}$

for a Moebius transformation $T(z)=\displaystyle{\frac{az+b}{cz+d}}$. To be honest I don't really understand how it works.

However, this leads to a division by zero for the given transformation in the $z$ equation. Is there a way to avoid this, or possibly an alternate transformation I could use?

Comment: "*pg. 91 of Indra's Pearls*" $-$ You should quote the relevant context in the question. Without it, the following equalities make no sense. If you want to write $T(z) = \frac{s(z-P)+rQ}{r} = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ then all you need to do is choose $a = s, b = -sP + rQ, c = 0, d = r$. When calculating $T(z)$ there is no division other than by $r \ne 0$ so it's hard to guess why and where you are getting one.

Comment: No, c = 0, so there's a division by 0 in the expression for z.

Comment: The "*expression for* $z$" is one of those equalities that make no sense because you don't explain where it comes from or what it's supposed to do. That aside, the division by $c$ there is an artifact of the particular way you chose to write it. The formula is equivalent to $z = P - \frac{r^2 \bar c}{\overline{c P + d}}$ which gives $z = P$ when $c=0$.